# formatting a number to a display string

Tags: oracle, plsql, to-char

Converting a number to a string for example `20000000.00` like this `20 000 000.00` with gap. Please help me

Comment: If i do like this to_char(as_number, '999G999G999G999G990D00') In my app it appears as a comma instead of a space

Comment: to_char(20000000.00, '999G999G999G990D00', 'nls_numeric_characters=''. SPACE''').  Thank you Littlefoot you are grate

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `to_char` function with `nls_numeric_characters` set to a dot (decimal point) and space (group separator):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 20000000.00 from dual union all
  3     select 12345.324   from dual)
  4  select to_char(col, '999G999G999G990D00', 'nls_numeric_characters=''. ''') result
  5  from test;

RESULT
-------------------
      20 000 000.00
          12 345.32

SQL>
```